# Nginx OpenSSL library install error

Tags: macos, nginx, rvm, passenger

I am on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), ran `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` and when building I ran into this error:

```
-lstdc++ -lpthread -lm /tmp/passenger.1rb7py0/pcre-8.34/.libs/libpcre.a -lssl -lcrypto -lz
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb", referenced from:
      _ngx_http_ssl_merge_srv_conf in ngx_http_ssl_module.o
  "_SSL_CTX_set_next_protos_advertised_cb", referenced from:
      _ngx_http_ssl_merge_srv_conf in ngx_http_ssl_module.o
  "_SSL_select_next_proto", referenced from:
      _ngx_http_ssl_alpn_select in ngx_http_ssl_module.o
  "_X509_check_host", referenced from:
      _ngx_ssl_check_host in ngx_event_openssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

From what I’ve read, it looks like either there is a library conflict and I have two include paths pointing to the same library, or Nginx is unable to find the correct library. The problem library appears to be the OpenSSL library. I have tried reinstalling RVM and passenger to no avail.

The only other post I could find that was very similar was [on openresty](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/513) which depends on OpenSSL.

Comment: Yes I did with no luck.

Comment: How do I set an explicit path to the new OpenSSL libraries?